# Sharepoint formula limit help

Tags: column, excel

i've been making this formula(based on previous questions) which works great(with 3 id's), But when i try it with all my id's it give me an error "Cannot complete this action". Can anyone help me out?

Its a column formula btw, wich is supposed to look at their value's and if the value is 2, it gives "Onacceptabel" and when the value is 0 or 1 it gives "Acceptabel"

> =IF( OR(INT([Aangelijnd Op De Rug])+INT([Aanlijning Voor Harnas Bereikbaar])+INT([Afzetting Van Werkplek Indien Van Toepassing
>   Oke])+INT([Als Het Werk Langer Duurt Dan Gepland Op
>   Vergunning])+INT([Ander Gereedschap Materiaal In
>   Orde])+INT([Bewegingsruimte En Bereikbaarheid In Orde])+INT([Bij Alarm
>   Waar De Vergunning In Te Leveren])+INT([Draagt Men Goed Sluitende
>   Kleding])+INT([Duwen Trekken Binnen Normale Grenzen])+INT([Electrisch
>   Handgereedschap In Orde])+INT([Gebruik Van Trapleuning])+INT([Geen
>   Geluidshinder])+INT([Geen Geur Overlast])+INT([Gevaar Identificatie
>   Aanwezig])+INT([GSM Gebruik Ex Proof])+INT([Harnas Goed Aangetrokken
>   Niet Te Los])+INT([Het Juiste Gereedschap Gebruikt])+INT([Is De
>   Groepsleider Op De Plant Aanwezig])+INT([Is De Handtekening
>   Groepsleider Gezet])+INT([Is De Handtekening Verg Overhandiger
>   Gezet])+INT([Is De Juiste Taal Gebruikt])+INT([Is Helm Nog
>   Goedgekeurd])+INT([Is Locatie Evacuatieplaats Bekend])+INT([Is Locatie
>   Intercom Bekend])+INT([Is Locatie Intercom Bekend])+INT([Is SWA Door
>   DOW Ondertekend])+INT([Juist Tussenstuk Gebruikt Bij Valshute Geen
>   Demper])+INT([Juiste Adembescherming Gedragen])+INT([Juiste
>   Gehoorbescherming])+INT([Juiste Handschoenen Voor Het
>   Werk])+INT([Juiste Valbescherming En Gekeurd])+INT([Kan Het Werk
>   Veilig Uitgevoerd Worden])+INT([Koude Warme Oppervlakken
>   Afgeschermd])+INT([Koude Warme Oppervlakken
>   Afgeschermd])+INT([Mogelijke Blootstelling
>   Gemeten])+INT([Omgevingstemperatuur In Orde])+INT([Ruimte
>   Bereikbaarheid In Orde])+INT([Spreekt De Groepsleider Ned Eng
>   Duits])+INT([Stoot Snijgevaar Afwezig])+INT([Struikel Uitglijgevaar
>   Afwezig])+INT([Tillen Dragen Binnen Normale
>   Grenzen])+INT([Uitleg-over-de-geïdentificeerde-gevaren-OK])+INT([Valblok
>   Boven De Persoon])+INT([Valblok Boven De Persoon])+INT([Verandering In
>   De Scope Van Het Werk])+INT([Verandering In De
>   Werkomstandigheden])+INT([Verlichting Reflectie Niet Hinderlijk In
>   Orde])+INT([Verlichting Voldoende])+INT([Vraag Meest Voor De Hand
>   Liggende Risico Ingevuld])+INT([Waar Naar Toe Te Gaan Bij
>   Attentiesignaal])+INT([Wat Vind U Hiervan])+INT([Weet Uitvoerende
>   Welke PBMs Standaard Zijn])+INT([Wisseling Van De
>   Groepsleider])+INT([Worden-de-geïdentificeerde-gevaren-beheerst])+INT([Wordt
>   Veiligheids Zuurbril Correct Gedragen])+INT([Zijn De Aangegeven
>   Beheersmaatregelen Genomen])+INT([Zijn De Open Vragen
>   Ingevuld])+INT([Zijn De Site Evacuatieplaatsen Bekend])+INT([Zijn Naam
>   Firma Datum Verg Nr Ingevuld]) = 3, INT([Aangelijnd Op De
>   Rug])+INT([Aanlijning Voor Harnas Bereikbaar])+INT([Afzetting Van
>   Werkplek Indien Van Toepassing Oke])+INT([Als Het Werk Langer Duurt
>   Dan Gepland Op Vergunning])+INT([Ander Gereedschap Materiaal In
>   Orde])+INT([Bewegingsruimte En Bereikbaarheid In Orde])+INT([Bij Alarm
>   Waar De Vergunning In Te Leveren])+INT([Draagt Men Goed Sluitende
>   Kleding])+INT([Duwen Trekken Binnen Normale Grenzen])+INT([Electrisch
>   Handgereedschap In Orde])+INT([Gebruik Van Trapleuning])+INT([Geen
>   Geluidshinder])+INT([Geen Geur Overlast])+INT([Gevaar Identificatie
>   Aanwezig])+INT([GSM Gebruik Ex Proof])+INT([Harnas Goed Aangetrokken
>   Niet Te Los])+INT([Het Juiste Gereedschap Gebruikt])+INT([Is De
>   Groepsleider Op De Plant Aanwezig])+INT([Is De Handtekening
>   Groepsleider Gezet])+INT([Is De Handtekening Verg Overhandiger
>   Gezet])+INT([Is De Juiste Taal Gebruikt])+INT([Is Helm Nog
>   Goedgekeurd])+INT([Is Locatie Evacuatieplaats Bekend])+INT([Is Locatie
>   Intercom Bekend])+INT([Is Locatie Intercom Bekend])+INT([Is SWA Door
>   DOW Ondertekend])+INT([Juist Tussenstuk Gebruikt Bij Valshute Geen
>   Demper])+INT([Juiste Adembescherming Gedragen])+INT([Juiste
>   Gehoorbescherming])+INT([Juiste Handschoenen Voor Het
>   Werk])+INT([Juiste Valbescherming En Gekeurd])+INT([Kan Het Werk
>   Veilig Uitgevoerd Worden])+INT([Koude Warme Oppervlakken
>   Afgeschermd])+INT([Koude Warme Oppervlakken
>   Afgeschermd])+INT([Mogelijke Blootstelling
>   Gemeten])+INT([Omgevingstemperatuur In Orde])+INT([Ruimte
>   Bereikbaarheid In Orde])+INT([Spreekt De Groepsleider Ned Eng
>   Duits])+INT([Stoot Snijgevaar Afwezig])+INT([Struikel Uitglijgevaar
>   Afwezig])+INT([Tillen Dragen Binnen Normale
>   Grenzen])+INT([Uitleg-over-de-geïdentificeerde-gevaren-OK])+INT([Valblok
>   Boven De Persoon])+INT([Valblok Boven De Persoon])+INT([Verandering In
>   De Scope Van Het Werk])+INT([Verandering In De
>   Werkomstandigheden])+INT([Verlichting Reflectie Niet Hinderlijk In
>   Orde])+INT([Verlichting Voldoende])+INT([Vraag Meest Voor De Hand
>   Liggende Risico Ingevuld])+INT([Waar Naar Toe Te Gaan Bij
>   Attentiesignaal])+INT([Wat Vind U Hiervan])+INT([Weet Uitvoerende
>   Welke PBMs Standaard Zijn])+INT([Wisseling Van De
>   Groepsleider])+INT([Worden-de-geïdentificeerde-gevaren-beheerst])+INT([Wordt
>   Veiligheids Zuurbril Correct Gedragen])+INT([Zijn De Aangegeven
>   Beheersmaatregelen Genomen])+INT([Zijn De Open Vragen
>   Ingevuld])+INT([Zijn De Site Evacuatieplaatsen Bekend])+INT([Zijn Naam
>   Firma Datum Verg Nr Ingevuld]) = 0),  "Acceptabel", "Onacceptabel" )

Comment: looks like length of calculated column is 1024, http://sharepointkb.wordpress.com/2009/02/10/calculated-column-limits-1024-characters/ and also check this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9acd357f-b329-473a-8f95-df7dfd62d1a2/maximum-numbers-of-characters-in-calculated-column?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Calculated Column character limit for SP2010, SP2013 or Office365 SharePoint is neither 1024 bytes neither 8192 bytes but **4000 bytes**

Your Formula is 4917 bytes

And can easily be split in 2 Calculated Columns, the first one doing part of the calculation and then using the result in the second column.

If you want to experience the 4000 characters limit yourself
just continue adding

```
&"0123456789"
```

to the Formula

```
="0123456789"&"0123456789"
```

Note that 4000 character limit is for compiled columns.
So adding 2 String columns of 2001 characters will result in an error

But a long Formula with multiple INT statements like yours will result in a Number of just a few characters.

Also note the limit is 48 Calculated Columns per List/Library

And you can also put JavaScript in Calculated Columns to execute in VIEWS...its an alternative for CSR/JSlink, and works in SharePoint 2010 and higher 
see [www.ViewMaster365.com](http://www.ViewMaster365.com)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint uses Excel engine for calculated columns:

According to [Excel specifications and limits](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005199291)
Length of formula contents  -   8,192 characters

I have put your formula in Excel 2010 and have got max length error (max 8192)